# hide .volumeicon.icns in dmg

Tags: macos, cocoa, dmg

I want to hide .volumeicon.icns in DMG file. Is it possible?

I try this on Terminal app

1. defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
2. killall Finder

But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

if it starts with `.` it is hided, it's your Finder that is set to show hided files, with

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE`

you will hide all hidden files, but on another machine with

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

it will still be seen.

---

There is no way to really hide it, what i do is to move all my hidden files outside of current visible area inside dmg.

In this way

- if Finder is set to not show hidden files you will not see it
- if Finder is set to show hidden files you will see a scrollbar (that is transparent on 10.7+)

As i know there is no better way...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetFile -a V .volumeicon.icns`

Use `xcrun SetFile` to run latest version provided by Xcode installation.